# как рассчитать deltaY в java?

Tags: java, ultralight

У меня есть ultralight-java, библиотека которая позволяет в java писать интерфейсы на html, но у меня возникла задача, как добавить скролл по колесику мыши. Он делается так

```java
viewController.getView().fireScrollEvent(new UltralightScrollEvent().deltaX(0).deltaY(deltaY).type(UltralightScrollEventType.BY_PIXEL));
```

Но вот возникла проблема, я получаю deltaY в формате 1 или -1, и умножаю на 30, если height видимой части будет ~500 то все будет нормально и привычно, как в браузере
но если будет 1000 то лично для меня это не привычно

как рассчитать дельту по y что бы было как в браузере?

я могу получить размер видимой части размер всего контента
https://imgur.com/a/nwqBy0u